# Adding HTML Elements from Elements collection into custom object list | JAVA

Tags: java, html, arraylist, collections, element

I am currently writing a Java program, which is already able to get html code from a website and parse it into a document (No file, but an Object of the java Document class).

It then extracts a Collection of Elements with the tags "table rows", because i only need the tables that are on the website (I'm using jsoup for this and also for the parsing).

If I then output the Elements object, everything is fine and i get the wanted html code parts with the tags . So the first part seems okay.

Now i want for each  element to add a custom object "TableRow" (with constructor parameters matching the text values of the  elements own child elements) to a new custom object List.
The List shall then contain as much objects as the Element collection contained Elements and the Text Values (of the child elements) shall be stored in the Variables of the Objects in the List.

Another possibility for me would be to store them into an XML File, but I don't know that much of XML storing, so I would prefer the List very much.

This is the code I already wrote:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.awt.List;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class table {
    //List to be filled with the custom Objects
    public ArrayList<tableLine> tableList = new ArrayList<tableLine>();

    public table(){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        //Creating the document and extracting the table rows
        Document site = Jsoup.connect("example.com").get();
        Elements rows = site.getElementsByTag("tr");
    }
}
```

And this is the custom object class:

```
import java.awt.List;

public class tableLine {
    String date;
    String course;
    int lesson;
    String subject;
    String text;


    public tableLine(String date, String course, int lesson, String subject, String text){
        this.date = date;
        this.course = course;
        this.lesson = lesson;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful with what List you are using... java.awt.List is suppoesed to be a UI component instead of abstract data structure. You should use java.util.List and its implementation from the same package. Just a kindly reminder though there isn't any actual usage of it.